# My Quicksort algorithm is running too slow

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am sorting 32 bit random integers using Quicksort algorithm. When I sort 10 or 100 or 1000 elements algorithm works quickly but when I choose n=10.000 it takes approximately 15minutes to sort. I want to increase n to 10000000 but then algorithm will take forever. I could not find what is wrong in my implementation.

Here is my main function

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){

    Random rand = new Random(new Date().getTime()); //different seed for each run

    createRandArray(rand);  
    long startTime= System.nanoTime();
    sort();
    long finishTime= System.nanoTime();
    }
```

Here is the implementation of Quicksort

```
  public static void sort(){
        int left = 0;
        int right = my_array.length-1;
        quickSort(left, right);
    }

    private static void quickSort(int left,int right){

        if(left >= right)
            return;

        BigInteger pivot = my_array[right];
        int partition = partition(left, right, pivot);

        quickSort(0, partition-1);
        quickSort(partition+1, right);

    }

    private static int partition(int left,int right,BigInteger pivot){
        int leftCursor = left-1;
        int rightCursor = right;

        while(leftCursor < rightCursor){

                while(my_array[++leftCursor].compareTo(pivot)==-1);
                while(rightCursor > 0 && my_array[--rightCursor].compareTo(pivot)==1);

            if(leftCursor >= rightCursor){
                break;
            }
            else{
                swap(leftCursor, rightCursor);
            }
        }

        swap(leftCursor, right);
        return leftCursor;
    }

    public static void swap(int left,int right){

        BigInteger temp = my_array[left];
        my_array[left] = my_array[right];
        my_array[right] = temp;
    }
```

This is how I create the 32 bit rand integer array

```
 public static void createRandArray(Random rand ){

        BigInteger big_int=new BigInteger("1"); //initialization

        for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
        big_int= new BigInteger(32, rand);
        my_array[i]= big_int;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you need 32 bit integer (which is exactly what `int` is) - don't use `BigInteger`. The comparison of `BigInteger` takes more time than comparing ints.

Comment: @alfasin yes you are right but I need 32 bit random integers, I do not know how to create random 32 bit int if I don't use BigInteger.

Comment: `int not_so_big_int= rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: @alfasin for a 32 bit integer, there is only 10 digits, and BigInteger comparison is similar to string comparison, which is O(n), so this is not a big issue.

Comment: @PhamTrung say that he work with an array of 1M elements and that the diff between the comparisons is 1 millisecond, that means more than 0.001*1000000*log(1000000)=1000*6=6000 seconds diff between the two (assuming quicksort requires n*log(n) comparisons). And since quick sort worse case is n^2, it could take much longer than that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming the lower bound is zero instead of `left` in a couple places hence you are doing more work than you need to:

in `quickSort(int left,int right)`:

`quickSort(0, partition-1);`
to
`quickSort(left, partition-1);`

and in `partition(int left,int right,BigInteger pivot)`:

`while(rightCursor > 0 && my_array[--rightCursor].compareTo(pivot)==1);`
to
`while(rightCursor > left && my_array[--rightCursor].compareTo(pivot)==1);`

Comment: @vandale Do you have any idea how long does it suppose to take to sort 1million 32 bit integers? approximately

Comment: @bug you could compare your times against the times for the built in Arrays.sort() function for a better idea